# Unable to get a security group ID by name using Graph API. Error "URI path is not a valid Graph endpoint," inside our power automate flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, power-platform

I want to get a security group ID by name, so i tried this HTTP request action, by passing this uri (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=displayname eq 'SEC-Project Repository Hub-Visitors'):-

[image]

but i got this error

```
{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "URI path is not a valid Graph endpoint, path is neither absolute nor relative or resource/object is not supported for this connector. Resources: groups. Uri: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=displayname eq 'SEC-Project Repository Hub-Visitors'",
"source": "canada-001.azure-apim.net",
"path": "choose[10]\\when[1]",
"policyId": "",
"clientRequestId": "*****"
}
}
```

any advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a "quirk" with both the Send an HTTP request and the Send an HTTP request actions. If you have a query string, you need to include a forward slash before the query string starts.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/?$filter=displayname eq 'SEC-Project Repository Hub-Visitors'
```

Comment: thanks it worked